# Drivers issue on 18.04? Touchpad buttons and printer not working

Tags: 18.04, printing, touchpad, thinkpad, button

Recently upgraded to 18.04 on Thinkpad E.

1) the 3 buttons over the touchpad (below space bar). Not working. (while touchpad endeed yes)
2) Installed Brother hl1200 drivers, seems to be perfectly installed, Ubuntu says "job is printed", printer receives a signal (one light) but then doesnt print.

For both things ive needed to install specific drivers in order to make it work on the previousthi 16 version. But now ive tried everything i was able to find. Glad to receive your feedback. thanks.